# What platform to use on a windows pc to implement an android accessory protocol?

Tags: android, windows, accessory

I am working on a project that requires me to setup **a windows pc as an accessory in order to communicate with an android phone**. My research has led me to discovering android open accessory protocol that enables an android device to be controlled by an accessory. Adding on, i have found lots of help on the internet on interfacing **ARDUINO MEGA ADK** with android enabled devices. However,i have found little to no information regarding implementation of an accessory protocol on a windows pc in order to achieve communication with an android enabled device. I would like to know what platform can be used for such a development and how can such a task be achieved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The discussions on [a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226272/android-device-acting-as-an-accessory) can shed some light on what you are trying to do. You might also want to look at [how to implement Android Open Accessory mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962709/how-to-implement-android-open-accessory-mode-as-a-service?rq=1).

Comment: Is the ADK used on windows to develop the accessory protocol?

Comment: See my answer - I tried to cover as much as possible. I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question like this is always difficult to address completely since it is not really a programming problem for which some workarounds and proven solutions can be readily provided. As a start, please read up on [Accessory Development Kit (ADK)](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html) - ADK is a reference implementation that can be used as a starting point for building accessories for Android. This sounds like what you are looking for. In terms of getting started, check out the guide based on ADK 2012 [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html) - the guide includes details on how the setup the development environment (which should address your question regarding the use of ADK to develop accessories for Android).

Furthermore, as already suggested, the discussions on a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226272/android-device-acting-as-an-accessory) can shed some light on what you are trying to do. You might also want to look at how to implement [Android Open Accessory mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962709/how-to-implement-android-open-accessory-mode-as-a-service?rq=1). If you encounter problem once you start developing or setting up the environment you can then post very specific questions.

Comment: I already looked up the recommended pages. I found links leading to linux and arduino environments but didn't find any help related to configuring windows as an accessory.